# What does the difference "a capsule preview" and "a capsule review "?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-order

What does the difference "a capsule preview" and
"a capsule review "?

Can you give me an example sentence  "a capsule preview" ?

Thankyou

Comment: I don't know what either of those things are. Where have you seen those terms? Please edit your question to give us the source(s)

Comment: @gotube  I have seem thees terms frequently, from many sources across many years. They do not come from a single source. They are perhaps most common in newspaper comment on books and movies. IIRC the NY Times Book Review used (some years ago) to have a whole subection of "capsule e reviews".

Answer (score 1):

"a capsule preview"  is a short summary of something addressed to those who have not yet seen, read, or listened to the work. It aims to let people know what sort of work it is, to judge whether to experience it
or not.

"a capsule review"  is a short critical comment on a work, intended to evaluate it, not just to describe it.